# Log the exceptions in separate files for each tenant in multi-tenancy architecture

Tags: java, spring, log4j, slf4j, multi-tenant

I have an application with multi-tenancy support, that is one server and multiple DB, there will be separate DB for each tenant. All the exceptions thrown in the application will be logged in one single log. The tenant ID will be printed along with the exception.

I would like to handle it in the separate file, i.e for each tenant a separate log file. This will be helpful in identifying that this exception is caused because of the activity is done by a user belonging to a particular tenant

Comment: Are you using log4j1.x or log4j2.x?